# AJAX hover tooltip displays returned data only for first row in table

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am sending data to a PHP page using AJAX, where the data is fetched from MySQL. Hovering over the `.payoudata` class sends its `data-id` value to PHP, and gets the result. It is displayed using `<div id="PayoutData">` but it's only displaying results related to the first record.

Here is my PHP code for generating the table:

```php
<? while($srow = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td id="tooltip1">
      <a href="#" class="payoudata" data-id="<?php echo $srow['application_no']?>"><?php echo $srow['application_no']?>
       <span><div id="PayoutData"></div></span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>  
<? } ?>
```

and here's my jQuery code for fetching and displaying the tooltip:

```js
$('.payoudata').hover(function(){

    var paydata =  $(this).attr("data-id");

    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'payout-emp-data.php',
        data:{paydata : paydata},
        success: function(paydataresult){
            $('#PayoutData').html(paydataresult);
            }
        });
    });
```

I am getting first record in this `<div id="PayoutData">`

When I try to see the second record it's sending data and getting a result but unable to display it, as shown in the screenshots below. What might be a potential way of displaying the returned data?

Screenshot of first record:

> [image: Screenshot]

Screenshot of second record:

> [image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you try to do the request manually, do you get all the rows back? Can you also include some of the html code that's generated with your script?

Comment: just to make sure that the problem is with the backend.. could you dump `paydataresult` varaible in your frontend.

Comment: yes i am getting result please see the screen shot added just now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generate a div with same id (PayoutData) for each row as id attribute should be unique. $('#PayoutData').html(paydataresult) will always get first one.

Try this for PHP:

```
<?php while($srow = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
         $rowId = $srow['application_no'];
?>                
   <tr>
      <td id="tooltip1">
         <a href="#" class="payoudata" data-id="<?= $rowId ?>"><?= $rowId ?>
           <span>
             <div id="PayoutData<?= $rowId ?>"></div>
           </span>
         </a>
      </td>
    </tr>  
<? } ?>
```

And Javascript :

```
$('.payoudata').hover(function(){

  var paydata =  $(this).attr("data-id");

  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'payout-emp-data.php',
    data:{paydata : paydata},
    success: function(paydataresult){
        $('#PayoutData' + paydata).html(paydataresult);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 3):

[HTML4 Specification says the `ID`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) must be unique.

> The id attribute assigns a unique identifier to an element (which may be verified by an SGML parser).

to solve this issue you will need to use classes rather than ids

replace this:

```
$('#PayoutData').html(paydataresult);
```

by:

```
$('.PayoutData', $(this)).html(paydataresult);
```

and this line:

```
<div id="PayoutData">
```

by:

```
<div class="PayoutData">
```

Comment: Good one! And easier than mine. Congrats!

Comment: yap very nice answer.